# how to sort local users by name in net core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

How to sort local users by name in net core 2.0?

```
new SelectList((_userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("MyRole").Result), "Id", "Fullname");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use `OrderBy` on your enumerable, before creating your `SelectList` instance. Also, don't use `Result`. You're going to cause deadlocks. Never block on an asynchronous request. Use `await` instead:

```
new SelectList((await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("MyRole")).OrderBy(x => x.FullName), "Id", "Fullname");
```